# Computer Restart because of Automatic Updates in WSUS

Tags: windows, networking, wsus, sccm, operating-system

I have configured SCCM and WSUS for Automatic Windows updates, Although updates are required,sometimes it cause different issues in computer system. As example After update on few months ago my LQ 300 printers didn't work, New update had been released by microsoft, Not only that sometimes computers restart automatically after update installation. what can i do for these issues, mainly i want to identify what are good updates and issues of them, have you any idea solve my issue,

Answer (score 2):

You have to prepare Pilot group of computers which can be used for testing purposes. They should have the services which your company uses.

Once you confirm that installing updates to the Pilot group doesn't cause any issues, you can go ahead and deploy the updates to the rest of computers.